# Open layers Angular how to adjust opacity with a slider

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, single-page-application, openlayers

I have a map thats generated on the components init that runs a method called makeMap() that creates a map that looks like follows

```
makeMap() {

  var osm = new TileLayer({
    source: new OSM(),
  });

  ...

  this.map = new Map({
    layers: [osm, wktLayer, this.tiles],
    target: 'ol-map',
    view: new View({
      center: proj.fromLonLat(coordinates),
      zoom: 9,
      minZoom: 8.75,
    }),
  });
}
```

I am trying to add a slider on the front end that can adjust the opacity of the layer "this.tiles". I have the following html for a slider. for testing right now im trying to adjust it as follows.

```
  setOpacity() {
    this.tiles.setOpacity(0);
    this.map.render()
  }
```

the issue is when I try to call the method after the map is created it doesnt update the layer only if I call it before its made. Im trying to connect it to a slider as follows

```
      <input
        id="opacity-input"
        type="range"
        min="0"
        max="1"
        step="0.01"
        value="1"
      />
```

How can I update the opacity of the layer when the slider changes value? I am new to angular and openlayers so im not sure how to create this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me like this with react:

```
<RangeInput onValueChanged={(value) => handleOpcitry(value)} />

const handleOpcitry = useCallback(
    (value: number) => {
      if (!osmLayer) {
        return;
      }

      const opacity = value / 100;

      console.log(opacity);

      osmLayer.setOpacity(opacity);
    },
    [osmLayer]
  );
```

Range Input:

```
<input
        type="range"
        min="0"
        max="100"
        value={100}
        onChange={handleValueChange}
></input>
```